# Fetching the resultsets from SQL Server 2016 in Mule (3.8.1) and Anypoint Studio(6.2.1)

Tags: mule, mule-component

In current Mule flow, I was able to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 and resultset is coming back in the form as {resultSet1=[{ROWEXISTS=1}]}. This will hit a flow variable rowExists and I will be taking further decision with the variable set. The value that I am expecting from the Stored procedure is 0 or 1 and it is correctly returned back in ROWEXISTS column. Now my question is how can I access the ROWEXISTS column from the resultset. I tried #[payload.get(0).ROWEXISTS] and #[payload.get(0)['ROWEXISTS']] etc. But with no luck. It will either give me an error or will be null.

The sample XML Payload that I am using is given below. I will extract the EmployeeNumber from the XML payload and execute a stored procedure to enrich the message. The target variable #[flowVars.rowExists]. But what I am looking here is the specific value of 0 or 1 that I get from the Stored procedure. 
I am unable to retrieve that value. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
 <Employees>
    <Employee>
            <CompanyCode>SMBMI</CompanyCode>
            <EmployeeLastName>LastName1</EmployeeLastName>
            <EmployeeFirstName>FirstName1</EmployeeFirstName>
            <MiddleName/>
            <EmployeeNumber>00479</EmployeeNumber>
            <Department>Public Safety</Department>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
            <CompanyCode>SMBMI</CompanyCode>
            <EmployeeLastName>LastName2</EmployeeLastName>
            <EmployeeFirstName>FirstName2</EmployeeFirstName>
            <MiddleName/>
            <EmployeeNumber>08945</EmployeeNumber>
            <Department>Transport</Department>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

The Mule flow xml is given below

```
<flow name="DBtest" >
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Backup\Files\Input" moveToDirectory="C:\Backup\Files\Output" connector-ref="FileGodsake" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="(EmployeeList){1}.*(\.xml)" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <splitter expression="#[xpath3('//Employee',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <enricher  target="#[flowVars.rowExists]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
            <db:stored-procedure config-ref="adventure" doc:name="Check Employee Exists">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{CALL EmployeeExists (:EmployeeNumber)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
                <db:in-param name="EmployeeNumber" value="#[xpath3('//EmployeeNumber',payload,'STRING')]"/>
            </db:stored-procedure>
        </enricher>
        <logger message="Employee Number:  #[xpath3('//EmployeeNumber',payload,'STRING')] and If Exists is #[flowVars.rowExists] . The get request #[flowVars.rowExists]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars.rowExists]">
                <db:stored-procedure config-ref="adventure" doc:name="Update Employee">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{CALL UpdateEmployee (:CompanyCode,:EmployeeLastName,:EmployeeFirstName,:MiddleName,:EmployeeNumber,:Department
,:DeptNumber)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
                    <db:in-param name="CompanyCode" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//CompanyCode',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="EmployeeLastName" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//EmployeeLastName',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="EmployeeFirstName" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//EmployeeFirstName',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="MiddleName" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//MiddleName',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="EmployeeNumber" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//EmployeeNumber',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="Department" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//Department',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                 </db:stored-procedure>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <db:stored-procedure config-ref="adventure" doc:name="Insert Employee">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{CALL InsertEmployee (:CompanyCode,:EmployeeLastName,:EmployeeFirstName,:MiddleName,:EmployeeNumber,:Department)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
                    <db:in-param name="CompanyCode" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//CompanyCode',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="EmployeeLastName" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//EmployeeLastName',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="EmployeeFirstName" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//EmployeeFirstName',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="MiddleName" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//MiddleName',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="EmployeeNumber" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//EmployeeNumber',payload,'STRING')]"/>
                    <db:in-param name="Department" type="VARCHAR" value="#[xpath3('//Department',payload,'STRING')]"/>                
        </db:stored-procedure>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
 </flow >
```

I wanted to have the value of ROWEXISTS extracted and updated to the target variable rowExists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this expression - `#[payload.resultSet1.get(0).ROWEXISTS]`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. But I tried this earlier. But was not helping. Also getting a warning message as: the expression returned a non Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I am going to give Credit to Senthil. The Enricher source should be

## [payload.resultSet1.get(0).ROWEXISTS==1]. This would evaluate to true or false based on whether the row is returned as 1 or 0